# Check if element does exist in WebBrowser using BackgroundWorker

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

I'm using background worker to manipulate some of the elements on my WebBrowser using vb.net.

For example the background worker `RFIDReader` will check if I'm on a specific link.

```
ElseIf TerminalBrowser.Url.ToString.Contains(baseUrl + "box-office/ticket-verification") And rf_code <> "" Then

    ' Insert RF Code in "rf_code" hidden text field
    Me.Invoke(Sub() Me.TerminalBrowser.Document.GetElementById("rf_code").SetAttribute("value", rf_code.ToLower))

End If
```

What happens here is, if I tap my RFID card. It will include that corresponding value to my `rf_code` element in my browser.

Now what I want to happen is, I want to check if the container itself (`synchronize-rfid`) does exist (Since it's a pop up). See image for reference.

[image]

Here's our code for that.

```
If Me.TerminalBrowser.Document.GetElementById("synchronize-rfid") IsNot Nothing Then
    ' Code here
end if
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2022120/1699388

The problem is, BackgroundWorker does not really interacts with UI as per the code above.

Is there any method for me to determine if that element exist using background worker?

I think I've done this and it does not work though.

```
Dim synchronize_rfid = Me.Invoke(Sub() Me.TerminalBrowser.Document.GetElementById("synchronize-rfid"))
If synchronize_rfid IsNot Nothing Then
    ' Code here
end if
```

Comment: What does " it does not work though" mean?  i.e. exception thrown, not the result you expect, etc.?

Comment: @TnTinMn, the code itself does not check if the element `synchronize_rfid` exist. I tried to send a message box inside the if statement, it does not go in though.

Comment: `Me.Invoke(Sub() Me.TerminalBrowser.Document.GetElementById("synchronize-rfid"))` will always return a value of Nothing as a subroutine does not return a value.  Assuming that TerminalBrowser is the proper reference, then you would need to be using a lambda function versus lambda method in your `Me.Invoke` statement.  The reason that I state "TerminalBrowser is the proper reference" is because you indicate that the element is in a popup window and that could be a different browser instance.

Comment: Not to be rude, but I cannot help but notice that you've been online a few times these days. Have you really had no time to test my answer, or are you just waiting for the bounty to end?

Comment: @VisualVincent, Not to be rude also, I may be online for the past few days, but that does not mean that I'm on my workplace. Please assume that I'm on a meeting / field / home. I still haven't tested your code. Please be patience. I'm not that mean to not award my hard worked reputation points.

Comment: Oh I am patient. It just seemed strange to not receive any kind of response, like a comment, or anything. I fully respect that you've not had the time to test it yet. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try declaring the variable first, then set it during the invocation (which will set it from the main thread).

The `Sub()` lambda behaves like a normal `Sub()`-`End Sub` method, which means you can do the same things in there as if you had a separate method.

This works for me:

```
Dim synchronize_rfid As HtmlElement
If Me.InvokeRequired = True Then
    Me.Invoke(Sub() synchronize_rfid = Me.TerminalBrowser.Document.GetElementById("synchronize-rfid"))
Else
    synchronize_rfid = Me.TerminalBrowser.Document.GetElementById("synchronize-rfid")
End If

If synchronize_rfid IsNot Nothing Then
    ' Code here
End If
```

Comment: Seems time is running out, I'll do this on my dummy page just to test if any element does exist using that code. I don't have necessary equipment to test where I should really test it. But it just works either way.

This one really works though, but I have a question. If I either comment / removed inside the if statement or else statement, it errors though.

Comment: Ohh, nevermind. It just said that it might result to null value, it just warned me. Thanks though.
My bad for the late response. Haven't communicating with you since I haven't tested it, doing couple of projects.

Comment: @WesleyLachenal : Oh there really was no hurry. I just checked because I thought it seemed strange that I hadn't received any response. Well I'm glad it worked for you. :)